# Update "Support"/"Contact Developer" Page for Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I don't get email-notifications when users leave support requests inside Chrome Web Store and for this reason want to show them the link to the existing support portal.

Something similar to the Loom Support Page

Can't find any information in the docs. Is it achievable?
[image: Loom Support Page]

Comment: If you don't see it in the dashboard, try switching to the old (classic) dashboard.

Comment: Could you please share what is the name of the setting I should be looking for?